# PHP won't compare same string

Tags: php, string-comparison

If I display `$d[0]` it is `liam.schnell@gmail.com` but it is refusing to accept the if...

```
$d = file("mails.txt");
if ($d[0] == "liam.schnell@gmail.com") {
    echo "JOW!";
}
echo $d[0];
```

Any idea?

Comment: There's probably a `newline` character at the end of `$d[0]`.

Comment: No, if I compare it to liam.schnell@gmail.com\n it doesn't trigger

Comment: You can use `var_dump` to better see the contents of variables, as it will escape pesky newlines and other things so you can see them.

Comment: `\r\n` is also considered a `newline` on some non *nix systems. Are you on a Windows box perhaps?

Comment: \r\n is for windows. \n is unix, and I believe older pre-osx macs used \r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling the [trim function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the `$d[0]`, which will remove all new line characters at the beginning and end of the string.

```
        $d = file("mails.txt");
        if(trim($d[0])=="liam.schnell@gmail.com"){
            echo "JOW!";
        }
        echo $d[0];
```

or not include any new lines at all:

```
        $d = file("mails.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        if($d[0]=="liam.schnell@gmail.com"){
            echo "JOW!";
        }
        echo $d[0];
```

> Each line in the resulting array will
>   include the line ending, unless
>   FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you
>   still need to use rtrim() if you do
>   not want the line ending present.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mike Lewis, using trim might fix why it was failing.

Also, in general, if you are having weird results in PHP when comparing strings, try '===' or strcomp to see that fixes the issue.

http://www.phpcatalyst.com/php-compare-strings.php

Comment: Or `strcasecmp` which is binary safe case-insensitive string comparison.

Answer (score 3):

```
$d = file("mails.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if ($d[0] == "liam.schnell@gmail.com") {
    echo "JOW!";
}
echo $d[0];
```